# What is exactly happening here? In my class the following derivation was done: factor with: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ and then ..

Tags: calculus

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} (l *\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}) = (g \sin y ) \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

Where the teacher used $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ as a new factor, multiplied both sides with this factor.

Then derived this:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} (\frac{1}{2} l *(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2) = (g \cos y ) \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

And afterwards integrated on both sides.

I have no clue how the factoring works and what actually you are doing. I can see the the $\sin$ gets differentiated, but how and why that is possible I don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to work backwards on this, and recognize how it works with the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial y'^2}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y'^2}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial y'}{\partial t} = 2y'y''$$